# Slick returns empty list when it should return an object

Tags: scala, orm, slick

I have an ApiCall table. I am trying to ensure that for each api call, the appropriate token was used. In plain english, what I think I'm doing here is filtering on `ApiCall` by `apiCallId`, then taking `headOption` (there should only be one b/c apiCallId is unique), then mapping on that. For some reason though, this function returns an empty `List()`...

```
def apiCallMatchesToken(apiCallId: ApiCallId, token: String): Future[Boolean] = {

val tableQuery = ApiCalls.filter(_.apiCallId === apiCallId).result.headOption

database.tryRun(tableQuery).map({
  case (a: ApiCallRow) => if (a.token == token) { true } else { false }
  case _ => false
})

}
```

I have double-checked that the `apiCallId` exists in my database. What's the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that `database.tryRun(tableQuery)` returns an `Option` of the type `ApiCallRow` ? I'd rather think that it should be something like `Future[Option[ApiCallRow]]`. In that it would always return `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable answer is that your Option[ApiCallRow] is wrapped into something added by tryRun function - it may be `Try[Option[ApiCallRow]]` or `Future[Option[ApiCallRow]]. Try using using a`flatMap` instead of a map or matching on an Option here:

`database.tryRun(tableQuery).flatMap({
  case Some(a: ApiCallRow) => return Future.successful(a.token == token) 
  case _ => Future.successful(false)
})`

Comment: Very close. I ended up needing the `flatMap`, `Some`, and to return `Future.successful`. I'll accept your answer, but you may want to change it to reflect that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Was not sure about the `tryRun` signature so had to make some guesses on the way :(. I've updated the answer, can you have a look if my answer is correct now?